# Does RightToLeft should be concerned with image?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have developed my own custom control with drawing images with text in control. And i draw text in left and image in right side of control.

I have provided RTL support for my control and modified the string format only based on RightToLeft enabled and the given text in the control is drawing fine based on RightToLeft.

My question is, should we change the position of text and image also considering righttoleft (Text in Left-Image in Right or Text in Right - Image in Left)

or just considering RightToLeft drawing for only the text of the control?

Please anyone suggest me your ideas.

Regards,
Amal Raj U.

Comment: This seems to be a question regarding UX design, I guess? There is another StackExchange site for UX.

Comment: Anybody that speaks right-to-left will expect text to be drawn RTL, starting from the upper-right of the window.  Which is already the way it works.  But images should be displayed as-is, that does require you to explicitly use Graphics.ScaleTransform() and TranslateTransform() to get correct output.

Comment: Sometimes users expect the images get mirrored in RTL layout. So you can provide `RightToLeftAutoMirrorImage` property like `ToolStripButton`. Then based on the value of the property decide about rendering. When `true` is set for the property, you can mirror the image when RTL is set.